# Is it possible to transfer images from Android to iOS programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi

I want to make apps running on Android and iOS device that can transfer an image between them.

I made a multi peer chatting app in iOS via Wifi.
And there're some codes for transferring text between Android devices via Bluetooth.

**Is it possible to transfer an image from Android to iOS device or vice versa?**

Comment: Practically speaking, it should work on unprivileged ports if you are on the same wifi.  Otherwise you need a mutually visible intermediate server, at the least to get things started.

Comment: How can I set the port in app? Please give me the tutors.

Comment: Asking for code generally gets questions closed here, so I suggest you try your own targeted web searches.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. How should I search it. keyword?